# Calculating Fourier Transform of $\sum_{n=1}^{3}\sin(2\pi \frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T})$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, signal-processing

This question deals with finding the Nyquist Frequency of a given signal.

Suppose you have the signal $x(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{3}\sin(2\pi \frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T})$ in the time domain where $T>0$ is some positive number.

Our goal is to find the nyquist frequency, or in other words, find $u_0$ such that $\forall u>u_0: \hat x(u)=0$ where $\hat x(u)$ is the fourier transform of $x(t)$.

If i understand correctly, to do that we need to find the fourier transform, and I have a few issues:

$\hat x(u) = \int_{\mathbb R}x(t)e^{-2\pi iut}dt=\int_{\mathbb R}\sum_{n=1}^{3}\sin(2\pi \frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T})e^{-2\pi iut}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{3}\int_{\mathbb R}\sin(2\pi \frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T})e^{-2\pi iut}dt$

We can use euler's identity:$sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ to get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{3}\int_{\mathbb R}\sin(2\pi \frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T})e^{-2\pi iut}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{3}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{2\pi i\frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T}}-e^{-2\pi i\frac{n}{8}\frac{t}{T}}}{2i}e^{-2\pi iut}dt$$

after multiplying the exponents, we will see the above integral is equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^{3}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{2\pi i t(\frac{n}{8t}-u)}-e^{-2\pi i t(\frac{n}{8t}-u)}}{2i}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{3}\int_{\mathbb R}\sin[2\pi t(\frac{n}{8T}-u)]dt$$

The last equality is true again from Euler's identity.

But the problem is that this integral does not converge. It is an improper integral over $\sin$ function...How do we evaluate this in order to find the fourier transform and find the nyquist frequency?

Comment: Since the thing is periodic, you want Fourier Series, not the Fourier transform.

Comment: Why? I don't see the connection. I can still take the fourier transform of a periodic signal cant i?

Comment: Well, as you noticed, it doesn't converge. For a Fourier Transform to converge, the function certainly has to decay at infinity. For periodic signals, you use Fourier series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your signal goes on forever, there is no frequency beyond which the FT is zero. Usually, the Nyquist frequency is the frequency beyond which there is no *significant* energy, where the definition of *significant* is to be determined by the user/designer/requirements. In the example you gave, this would just be $3/8T$, the largest frequency in the sum of sinusoids.

However, if you give bounds to your signal in the time domain such that $x(t)=0$, $t \notin [-T,+T]$, you'll find the integral is solvable and each $\sin$ function will transform to two $\operatorname{sinc}$ functions centered on the positive and negative frequency of the sinusoid. The larger $T$ is, the narrower the $\operatorname{sinc}$ functions will be and as $T\rightarrow \infty$, the $\operatorname{sinc}$'s will approach impulse functions.